# Cannot resolve symbol 'tools' and 'GradleException'

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

I have started to work on an existing project including Android NDK. I have two issues in build.gradle, which is impossible for me to build the app. For your information, my co-worker (who was working on it) was able to build the app.

I have already imported the NDK, from the project structures I can see the correct Android NDK path.

Here is how build.gradle looks like :

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
    // quickly to Android tooling updates
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.21.5'
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
dataBinding{
    enabled = true;
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.lucien.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"

    ndk {
        moduleName "DSPLib-jni"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = [] // disable automatic ndk-build call, which ignore our Android.mk
sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'

// call regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    workingDir file('src/main')
    commandLine getNdkBuildCmd()
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}

task cleanNative(type: Exec) {
    workingDir file('src/main')
    commandLine getNdkBuildCmd(), 'clean'
}

clean.dependsOn cleanNative

}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'

compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.5'
compile 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'

}

def getNdkDir() {
if (System.env.ANDROID_NDK_ROOT != null)
    return System.env.ANDROID_NDK_ROOT

Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
def ndkdir = properties.getProperty('ndk.dir', null)
if (ndkdir == null)
    throw new GradleException("NDK location not found. Define location with ndk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_NDK_ROOT environment variable.")

return ndkdir

}

def getNdkBuildCmd() {
def ndkbuild = getNdkDir() + "/ndk-build"
if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS))
    ndkbuild += ".cmd"

return ndkbuild

}
```

I have an issue with the first line, trying to import "org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os" : Cannot resolve symbol 'tools'

[image: tools issue]

And the same kind of issue for "throw new GradleException("...")"

[image: GradleException issue]

Do I need to update something in my build.gradle ? Or the issue is somewhere else ?

Thanks !

Comment: Could you share Gradle version you have?  And is it the same version as your co-worker has?

Comment: Hi Stanislav, I'm using Gradle 2.14.1 and my co-worker too.

Comment: It's been 3 weeks, did you resolve this?

Comment: Yes I did, it was an issue with Android Studio 2.2 beta, it's working fine with the stable channel in version 2.1 and new version 2.2 (stable version)

Comment: Still an issue for me. I cannot resolve the above problem in my build.gradle.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use any other available exceptions from java like:

```
throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not read version.properties!")
```

Comment: Works with a Flutter project too. Android Studio 3.5

Answer (score 20):

very simple delete  **new**  from build.gradle

Answer (score 6):

throw ***new*** GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")

delete ***new***

throw GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")

Comment: Worked for me. `new` was inserted by the Flutter new project tool for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found")

Comment: This answer is exactly the same than https://stackoverflow.com/a/42715666/4862968, please do not post duplicates and upvote the original answer instead.

Answer (score -1):

For those who come here, I resolved my issue by going back to Android Studio 2.1. Since the release of stable version 2.2, it's working great.

Comment: how to go back to Android Studio 2.1?

Comment: @K.Sopheak You can find old version of AS here : http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary

Comment: I am getting in Android Studio v3.5 too.

Comment: Android 4.0.1 - this is still an issue.